# Hyperloop; Which Open-Source License did Musk choose?

Tags: usa, transportation, licensing, open-source

Which Open-Source license did Elon Musk choose for the Hyperloop?

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, I can find no mention of license/patent/rights in the [Hyperloop Alpha PDF](http://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/hyperloop_alpha.pdf) published by Musk in 2013. In [a tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/356779314043305985), Musk stated:

> I really hate patents unless critical to company survival. Will publish Hyperloop as open source.

I sent an email to hyperloop@teslamotors.com inquiring. I'll update this answer if I hear back.

Comment: I originally searched that PDF along with Google, Wikipedia etc. I just now searched again, but still found nothing. It seems pretty obvious that he does not have a profit motive - I believe he just wants the idea to benefit society. So I was curious which licence he felt was best for this sort of altruism.

Comment: Hi @Joe Germuska . Any response from your email?

Comment: Nothing as of yet.